# Can I delete every message I've sent in a gc on telegram using a python bot?

Tags: python, telegram

Is it possible to make a python script that logs into a users account and deletes all messages they've sent in a specific private group chat they're in upwards of 6000 messages?

Comment: I'd suggest using the `pyautogui` module to do this. It's probably easier than working your way through the API.

Comment: Yes, telegram provides mtproto to make userbots which you can deploy to your account and use required methods to do your task, there are couple of libraries available in python which make your task even more easier, e.g. [pyrogram](https://github.com/pyrogram/pyrogram)

Comment: @Mous That would be very hard task to implement such things via pyautogui...

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that with Telegram bot API. But that can be done with a telegram client libraries such as [Pyrogram](https://pyrogram.org/)